# How to change font color after select item from textview in Material-UI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a select textview in my react app. How to change the font color after I select the item from this textview.

```
<div>
        <TextField
          id="standard-select-currency"
          select
          fullWidth
          label="Filter By"
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
            style: { color: "#fff" }
          }}
          margin="normal"
          value={this.state.filter}
          onChange={this.handleChange("filter")}
        >
          {currencies.map(option => (
            <MenuItem
              key={option.value}
              value={option.value}
              selected
              classes={{ selected: classes.selected }}
            >
              {<div style={divStyle}>{option.label}</div>}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>
      </div>
```

This is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-e34pv) I created for this case.

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const homePageStyle = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "300px"
  },
  selected: {
    backgroundColor: "turquoise !important",
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: 600
  }
});

const divStyle = {
  color: "red"
};

const listStyle = {
  color: "black"
};

const currencies = [
  {
    value: "USD value",
    label: "usd label"
  },
  {
    value: "EUR value",
    label: "eur label"
  },
  {
    value: "BTC value",
    label: "btc label"
  },
  {
    value: "JPY value",
    label: "jpy label"
  }
];

class SimpleMenu extends React.Component {
  state = {
    anchorEl: null,
    filter: ""
  };

  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
  };

  handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
    console.log(name + "   " + event.target.value);
  };

  render() {
    const { anchorEl } = this.state;
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <TextField
          id="standard-select-currency"
          select
          fullWidth
          label="Filter By"
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
            style: { color: "#fff" }
          }}
          margin="normal"
          value={this.state.filter}
          onChange={this.handleChange("filter")}
        >
          {currencies.map(option => (
            <MenuItem
              key={option.value}
              value={option.value}
              selected
              classes={{ selected: classes.selected }}
            >
              {<div style={divStyle}>{option.label}</div>}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(homePageStyle)(SimpleMenu);
```

In this example,you can see the font color is all red when I open the drop down list. After I select the item. The main label show the item which I selected with red font color. However, I want the main label show with blue color. How to achieve this?

Comment: NEVER post images of code, output or errors! And you are required to post your code here, within your question, and not a third party site.  [mcve]

Comment: @Rob ,noted and edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Just add

```
InputProps={{
            classes: {
                input: classes.input
            }
        }}
```

into your TextField and set the color you want in `classes.input`.
So the TextField will look like

```
<TextField
          id="standard-select-currency"
          select
          fullWidth
          label="Filter By"
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
            style: { color: "#fff" }
          }}
          InputProps={{
            classes: {
                input: classes.input
            }
        }}
          margin="normal"
          value={this.state.filter}
          onChange={this.handleChange("filter")}
        >
```

and the `homePageStyle` will set like

```
const homePageStyle = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "300px"
  },
  selected: {
    backgroundColor: "turquoise !important",
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: 600
  },
  input:{
    color: "blue",
  }
});
```

Lastly,remove `style={divStyle}`
If not, it will only display this style.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a react guy but would you like to try some css e.g.

```
<select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option selected>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
```

and css as

```
select { 
    color: black;
    background: red; 
   }
option:not(:checked) { 
      background: green;
 }
```

[Here is some one fiddle to try](http://jsfiddle.net/kQ6c5/)